# Undecidability of a set of Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, rice-theorem

Considering the following set, I have to say if it is undecidable, decidable or semidecidable:
$$S_1 = \{y | \forall n \text{ the Turing Machine } M_y \text{ does not accept any string of length } n\}$$

The answer given by the professor is:

> Set $S_1$ is undecidable, which can be justified based on the Rice Theorem.

I can't understand why. I would say that for a Turing Machine is trivial to find out if a string is of a given length, therefore I can't understand why it is undecidable based on the Rice Theorem. Can you please provide me an explanation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The set $S_1$ consists of all indices of Turing machines which don't accept any strings.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you for pointing that out, but I still don't understand why it should be undecidable, TMs can trivially accept empty strings. Am I right?

Comment: An index of a Turing machine is in $S_1$ iff the Turing machine rejects all strings. There's nothing special about the empty string.

Comment: if for all $n$, you do not accept strings of length $n$, then you don't accept any strings.

Comment: @lox thank you for answering, I got this point, but It still isn't clear to me why it shouldn't be this set decidable.